# Error during django-allauth[mfa] . could not build wheels for django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

when i want to install django-allauth[mfa] i got this error :

```
Using cached typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: django-allauth
  Building wheel for django-allauth (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Building wheel for django-allauth failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\\wpsystem\\s-1-5-21-474952578-913561270-2101499973-1001\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local\\pip\\cache\\wheels\\84\\10\\7b\\c9dbe47c3a955c9fa89b5cae6891d952195bac10d4a6b3650c\\django_allauth-0.61.1-py3-none-any.whl'
Failed to build django-allauth
ERROR: Could not build wheels for django-allauth, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

what is it about how can i fix it?

a little details :

i cloned github of cookiecutter-django and tried to install dependencies through pip , but i encountered this error. i commented the line for django-allauth in requirements.txt file out , then after installing other dependencies finished i tried to install django-allauth[mfa] alone but still the above error came up in the powershell.

Comment: We’ll need more details. What is your python version? What version of django are you using? Show your requirements.txt